# Garbage-collection of custom blocks in OCaml

Tags: garbage-collection, ocaml

Section [19.6](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual033.html) from the OCaml docs have this function to allocate a window block:

```
/* Allocating an OCaml custom block to hold the given WINDOW * */
static value alloc_window(WINDOW * w)
{
  value v = alloc_custom(&curses_window_ops, sizeof(WINDOW *), 0, 1);
  Window_val(v) = w;
  return v;
}
```

This is the only allocation function in the example. Assumably, `WINDOW` should be allocated else where - but how will it then be collected?

**Edit**: Oh, the `finalize` function in the `curses_window_ops` struct... Please ignore me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example code, curses windows are allocated by an external function:

```
external newwin: int -> int -> int -> int -> window = "curses_newwin"
```

Windows in curses are deleted by `delwin`. The example code doesn't provide a way to call this function, as far as I can see.

In an actual app you could imagine calling `delwin` in the finalization code for the OCaml window wrapper, but this sort of thing is problematic. It's not really possible to predict when finalization code will run. You don't want a window hanging around on the screen for an unknown period of time.

More likely you would want to provide an OCaml call to explicitly delete a window. This would leave the OCaml window wrapper in a zombie state. I.e., it would be up to the programmer to remember that the object no longer represents a window on the screen. Eventually it would be collected by GC (when no longer accessible).

You could make handling of short-term windows a little nicer by defining a higher-order function like `with_window`. It would take charge of deleting the window at the end, so there's no way for a zombie window to hang around.